# Get id of element and post in sql query?

Tags: php, jquery

Hey, I am trying to get the id of an element and then post that id in a sql query like this:

jQuery gets id of checkbox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(":checkbox").change(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.post("index.php", { id: this.id, checked: this.checked },
            function(data){
              alert("Data Loaded: " + id);
            }
        );
       //return false to insure the page doesn't refresh
    });    
});
```

Then I insert that into the php query, but it doesn't display anything on the page. What am I missing?

```
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM explore WHERE category IN ('".$_POST["id"]."') 
ORDER BY category LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code that's intended to display something on the page. You would need at the very least to 1° write some PHP code to execute the query and output its results ans 2° use the "data" argument to your post callback. 

Also, as written, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use mysql_real_escape_string, or prepared statements.

Comment: ` but it doesn't display anything on the page.`, yes but the problem is *how* did you display it?? you did not include info about that...

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(":checkbox").change(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.post("index.php", { id: $(this).attr('id'), checked: $(this).attr('checked') },
            function(data){
              alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            }
        );
       //return false to insure the page doesn't refresh
    });    
});
```

Also you point to checked property inside your function, but there is no such thing.

Comment: seriously, if the OP got a problem, this answer can make it worst.. ;)

Comment: `alert("Data Loaded: " + $(this).attr('id'));`, `this` refers to???, theres no problem in the client side part of the OP... I think it's in the server-side..

Comment: to illustrate `this.id`, `this.checked` is just fine as long as `this` refers to the right object, play with this demo http://jsfiddle.net/4gGLM/

Answer (score 0):

Ok using **antyrat** code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $(":checkbox").change(function(){ 
        var id = $(this).attr('id'); 

        $.post("index.php", { id: $(this).attr('id'), checked: $(this).attr('checked') }, 
            function(data){ 
              //alert("Data Loaded: " + data); 
$('#output').html(data);
            } 
        ); 
       //return false to insure the page doesn't refresh 
    });     
});
```

create a `<div id="output"></div>` within the body tag which is where the jquery will write the response too.